# How to check if not yet autoloaded class exists

Tags: php, oop, symfony, namespaces

In Symfony2 I want to check if a class file can be found **before** using it (meaning before *autoloading* it)

Is there a Symfony component to test whether the class file exists in one of the class paths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php). The function's second argument specifies whether autoloader should be called or not if the class hasn't been defined.

Comment: yeah, but if the class hasn't been autoloaded it will get autoloaded - even if it won't be used in the code. That's a huge waste of memory

Comment: @hek2mgl Your solution, on the other hand, requires an assumption that Symfony's default autoloader is the *only* active autoloader and that the files do, in fact, contain class definitions. It is the correct answer to OP's question now that *you* have rephrased it, though :]

Comment: Note that I have just rephrased it to prevent it from getting closed and I'm pretty sure that the OP wanted to ask this. Your concerns are valid of course, however importing the class just to know if I could include it is also not perfect in many solutions. Best would be to make sure that just 1 autoloader is running and ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symfonys [class loader](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html). Like this:

```
if(!$loader->findFile("\Namespace\Sub\Class")) {
    echo "file not found";
}
```

Comment: it's not working. $classLoader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassLoader();
        $ret = $classLoader->findFile('\xxx\SomeBundle\Vendor\Driver\Driver'); returns NULL but below I have a a "new \xxx\SomeBundle\Vendor\Driver\Driver()" which does work.

Comment: You need to use the class loader of symfony, which has already been initialized